# How to detect MMS fully downloaded in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, mms

I want to implement a BroadcastReceiver that is triggered after a MMS is *fully downloaded*.  I already know about the `android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED` action but this is triggered when the first part of the message is received, not when the message is fully downloaded (which is when the new message indicator icon shows up).

After some digging, I found an action called `android.intent.action.TRANSACTION_COMPLETED_ACTION` in the Messaging source code (`/src/com/android/mms/transaction/TransactionService.java`) that I *think* is used after an MMS is downloaded, but my BroadcastReceiver doesn't seem to get called when this action happens, so I'm not sure if the action just isn't broadcasted or what's going on.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out - at least a solution that works for me.

I've created a `ContentObserver` (which I didn't know existed when I asked this question) that listens to the URI `content://mms-sms/` and children for changes.  It gets called several times in the MMS receiving process, one of which seems to occur after the MMS is downloaded.

Comment: I was able to get my BroadcastReceiver to receive the `TRANSACTION_COMPLETED_ACTION` with this intent filter:
 <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TRANSACTION_COMPLETED_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: i have used same way.. but issue is that it's getting called so late(delay of half minute).. and all other apps are displaying too early.. as a  comparison. so am i missing something?? can you help??