# Detecting New SMS/MMS message Android application

Tags: java, android, sms, mms

can anyone tell how can I make my application knows if there's a new SMS or MMS messages come to the native InBox Messages ???

I want to make my application  knows if there's a new message please can anyone inform me , 
will be appreciated

Samiah

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages

Comment: @Pleerock Thanks for u all, I used this code for SMS and it works ... I want same code for MMS I have searched for long time but I couldn't find anything useful :(

Comment: @alextsc if you do not have an answer that make my project easier then please do not waste my time!there is many people think my question is good and also need the answers.please read the StackOverFlow rules:BE NICE!

Comment: @alextsc can you please be a first and give the favor?

Comment: @alextsc thanks alot and good luck in ur life =)

Answer (score 0):

Try using SMS broadcast receivers. take a look at [this](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/) and [this](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/) as well.

Comment: Thanks for u all, I used this code for SMS and it works ... I want same code for MMS I have searched for long time but I couldn't find anything useful :( ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016 and [this](http://androidbridge.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html)

these results are pretty up o n the google search. make sure you research properly before asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329819/detecting-mms-messages-on-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726158/how-to-detect-mms-fully-downloaded-in-android

these discussions talk a lot about what you are looking for. i m not sure about the feasibility of it. i m sure till before 2.1 it wasnt really possible, i dont know of it now. i hope these turn out helpful.